# Cakephp: problems with paginator and json array as argument of the controller

Tags: json, cakephp, pagination

I Have the controller's function "display" expecting an array encoded with JSON :

```
public function display($json_data){
pr($this->passedArgs);
    $matches = json_decode($json_data,true);
    $ids = array_keys($matches);

    $this->Version->recursive = 0;
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

    $name='Versions';
    $class='Version';
    $items = $this->Paginator->paginate(null,array("`".$class."`.id"=>$ids));
    $fields= $this->Version->schema();
    $ignore=array('');
    $this->set(compact('items','fields','name','class','ignore','matches'));
}
```

And in the display.ctp view, i have something very similar to the cookbook examples with something like:

```
<?php 
    echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->prev('&#171', array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button prev','escape'=>false), null, array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button prev','escape'=>false)).'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','class'=>'pure-button','currentClass'=>'pure-button pure-button-active')).'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->next('&#187', array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button next','escape'=>false), null, array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button next','escape'=>false)).'</li>';
?>
```

The array '$matches' is the one who shall b eused as input argument of the controller.

And to be more precise, on the first call to "display" method, from another view than display.ctp, the array 'matches' is endcoded in JSON and the treatment is correct.
The array is kept and sent to the display.ctp view. And when I click on next or previous link of the paginator control, the array sent to the controller is worngly coded.
It seems like characters "%25" are converted into "%" where they shouldn't : it's like an html-encoding problem on the json string and making it wrong.
I get the error:

```
Error: The requested address /application/versions/display/%7B%223%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%224%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%225%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%226%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%227%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%228%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%229%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2210%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2211%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2212%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2213%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2214%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2215%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2216%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2217%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2218%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2219%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2220%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2221%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2222%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2223%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%2224%22%3A%5B%22name%22%5D%7D/page:2' was not found on this server.
```

and if I look at the working string (previous to display view), i got:

```
    http://nas/application/versions/display/%257B%25223%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25224%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25225%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25226%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25227%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25228%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%25229%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252210%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252211%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252212%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252213%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252214%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252215%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252216%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252217%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252218%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252219%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252220%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252221%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252222%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252223%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%252C%252224%2522%253A%255B%2522name%2522%255D%257D
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something ?

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, just to close the topic: I have found the answer:

I just had to re-encode the url previous to pass it to the paginator, and then to force the array as argument:

```
    <?php 

        $matches_json = urlencode(json_encode($matches));
        echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->prev('&#171', array('url'=>array($matches_json),'tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button prev','escape'=>false), null, array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button prev','escape'=>false)).'</li>';
        echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','class'=>'pure-button','currentClass'=>'pure-button pure-button-active')).'</li>';
        echo '<li>'.$this->Paginator->next('&#187', array('url'=>array($matches_json),'tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button next','escape'=>false), null, array('tag'=>'div','class' => 'pure-button next','escape'=>false)).'</li>';
    ?>
```